# Detect 404 image status on angularjs when click on a button

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following button directive :

```
 <button-data></button-data>
```

the button data directive template is:

```
<div class="buttonDiv">
<a ng-show="!isSomthing" class="{{className}}" >
</a>
</div>
```

in another place , I have a canvas (some plugin) that show an image

When clicking on the button I would like to check if the image response is **404** or other broken status and disable the button in that case(event just return in the "link" directive function without doing anything)

- I have the image link in the scope of the button directive

Hos could I do that?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to get it before you display it. A simple `$http` get request is what you are looking for:

#### View

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button load-image image-src="imageSource">check photo</button>
  <button load-image image-src="imageSourceInvalide">check photo</button>
</div>
```

#### AngularJS application

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.imageSource = 'https://i.imgur.com/hlF1AEug.jpg';
  $scope.imageSourceInvalide = 'https://i.imgur.com/nonono';
});


myApp.directive('loadImage', function($http) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      imageSrc: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      element.on('click', function() {
        $http.get(scope.imageSrc).then(function(data) {

          element.append('<img src="' + scope.imageSrc + '">');

        }, function errorCallback(response) {
          console.log('could not load image');
        })
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**> [demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kdfvdev6/)**